# JasperReports MongoDB List Data

Tags: list, mongodb, jasper-reports

I am fairly new to *JasperReports* and am having a challenge getting list data to show up correctly from *MongoDB*.

I was working off of an [article](http://mdahlman.wordpress.com/2012/02/03/collections-in-reports-on-mongodb/#comment-611), but cannot seem to get it to work.

I have the following collection in *MongoDB*:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51e24462945f8796ea8e731d"), "id" : "1001", "cust" : "abc", "
lines" : [      {       "line number" : "line1",        "product" : "ProdA" },
{       "line number" : "line2",        "product" : "ProdB" } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51e246fb945f8796ea8e731e"), "id" : "1002", "cust" : "abc", "
lines" : [      {       "line number" : "line1",        "product" : "ProdA" },
{       "line number" : "line2",        "product" : "ProdB" } ] }
```

"lines" is a collection.

In *iReport*, it shows up as a list, which is good.  However, when I do as the article suggests and change the sub datasource to *`new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRMapCollectionDataSource($F{lines})`*, I still get the *List* as a string, which just shows up as

```
[[line number : line1, product: ProdA],[line number : line2, product: ProdB]]
```

Shouldn't using this *JRMapCollectionDataSource* parse this out for me already?  If not, how do I handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to access the list data by using field names "lines.line number" and "lines.product"? That might do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out.  You have to create an empty data set and from there map the fields to the ${lines} array.  For anyone that finds themselves in the same predicament as myself, I highly recommend reading the example JRXML file the author put into the article (something I didn't notice was there at first).

Thanks